# Can't Attach Image to MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimage, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller, messageui

I'm doing the following, but when logging, it always returns that the image could not be attached. What's wrong here?

```
- (void)showInvitation {

if (![MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {

    UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your device doesn't support SMS!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [warningAlert show];
    return;
}

NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Download this game!"];
MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
[messageController setBody:message];

if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendAttachments]) {
    NSLog(@"Attachments Can Be Sent.");
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"water"];
    BOOL didAttachImage = [messageController addAttachmentData:imgData typeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypePNG filename:@"image.png"];

    if (didAttachImage) {
        NSLog(@"Image Attached.");

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Image Could Not Be Attached.");
    }
}

[self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: What account is it? Perhaps your ISP blocks MMS? Try with iMessage.

Comment: It does say that attachments can be sent when I log it into the console. How can I try with imessage?

Comment: Actually yeah I'm using iMessage.

Comment: Why not add the attachment as file? You already have it on disk, create an `NSURL` and use the other method.

Comment: Wow! That actually ended up working! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, use `addAttachmentURL:withAlternateFilename:`. My guess is, the `NSData` object you provide does not fit the `kUTTypePNG` type and adding the attachment fails.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. It is working fine for me.

```
 if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {


            let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()

controller.body = "Solution of broken image in composer while sending through MFMessageComposserViewController "


            controller.messageComposeDelegate = self

            if image.imageAsset != nil {

                let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.fixOrientation(img: image), 1)  //! as NSData
                controller.addAttachmentData(imageData! , typeIdentifier: "image/.jpeg", filename: "image.jpeg")

            }

            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: {
                completion(true)
            })


        }
        }
```

Comment: The question is already answered and solved. It is unlikely that the OP will use this because the question is 3 years old.
Also please be carefull with your formatting.